# Join the result of a Temp column to a table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server to create my database.

I want to add a column to my Table which would calculate the number of NULL values in each row, like this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Score
a       |   B     |   C     |   0
x       |   NULL  |   NULL  |   2
```

Currently, I have this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
a       |   B     |   C     
x       |   NULL  |   NULL
```

I have created a new column called Score, and in order to calculate it, I have used:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN Column1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE WHEN Column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN Column3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
As TMP
FROM MyTable
```

That returns a column with all my lines and the Score for each line:

```
  |TMP
1 |0
2 |2
```

I would like to update the column Score in myTable with those values.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store calculated values depending on other columns. (Data redundancy, risk of data inconsistency.) Create a view instead. Or manage using triggers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a computed column - a virtual column that is always computed with a given expression, and not stored on disk. This way, you avoid problems with data consistency. The syntax is easy:

```
CREATE TABLE myTab
(
    column1 datatype
  , column2 datatype
...
  , Score AS CASE WHEN Column1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN Column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN Column3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
);
```

In order to alter the existing table and add such a column, use:

```
 ALTER TABLE myTab ADD Score AS CASE WHEN Column1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN Column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN Column3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

Comment: The problem is that my Table Is already Created with Data, Your query means that I should Create a new table isn't it ?

Comment: Or alter the existing one. `ALTER TABLE myTab ADD Score As ...`

Comment: Just a question for next time, if my Column Score is already created, How can I do to Update and Not to create a new Column ?

Comment: You'd have to drop it (`ALTER TABLE myTab DROP COLUMN score`) and re-create it as above.

Comment: What you mean by 'update'? If values change, then your computed column values change accordingly, no updating needed. If your computation logic changes then yes, you have to drop and recreate such column.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a bad idea to store calculated values depending on other columns. (Data redundancy, risk of data inconsistency.) Create a view instead:

```
create view MyView as
SELECT column1, column2, column3,
       CASE WHEN Column1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN Column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN Column3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As TMP
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1 The only thing is that i dont want to create a view, but update my table

Comment: If you really want to have those computed values in a base table, do as marmarta suggested to avoid the risk of data inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    Column1 CHAR(1),
    Column2 CHAR(1),
    Column3 CHAR(1),
    Score AS (
        CASE WHEN Column1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN Column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Column3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
)
```

or

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_Table
AS
    SELECT
          t.Column1
        , t.Column2
        , t.Column3
        , Score = (
            SELECT COUNT(t.val)
            FROM (
                VALUES
                    (t.Column1),
                    (t.Column2),
                    (t.Column3)
            ) t(val)
        )
    FROM dbo.test t
GO
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl
    ADD Score AS (
        CASE WHEN Column1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN Column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Column3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PERSISTED
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
+1
The only thing is that i dont want to create a view, but update my table

Comment: Perfect That's The Answer
Can you Explain to me what is the role of PERSISTED

Comment: PERSISTED mean that sql server physically store computed columns in the table without compute scalar operation

Comment: +1 To you
I just Accepted The answer of @mamarta because he/she was faster :(
but it's the same answer, really thank you :)

Comment: Just a question for next time, if my Column Score is already created, How can I do to Update and Not to create a new Column ?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE mt
SET Score = t.Tmp
FROM MyTable mt INNER JOIN (SELECT idx, 
    CASE WHEN Column1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN Column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN Column3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM MyTable) t ON t.idx = mt.idx
```

Comment: idx You mean that I should Create an index on my table ?
and t.Tmp you didn't forget to add As Tmp somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, to have an index would be a good idea. You're right, I forgot to add it as alias for second column